# How to create a function that can transform the last word into Uppercases?

Tags: php, string, function, uppercase

How do i create a function replaceMe() in php that would turn:

```
$str = 'This is a very long string';
```

into:

```
'This is a very long STRING?'
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

You apparently want to do a regular expression substitution, anchored at the end of the line. Use [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$str = 'This is a very long string';

# This is a very long LINE
echo preg_replace("/string$/", "LINE", $str);
```

For a general case, you can provide a callback instead of a replacement string, and simply uppercase the matched substring with [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$str = 'This is a very long blah';

function word_to_upper($match) {
  return strtoupper($match[1]);
}

# This is a very long BLAH
echo preg_replace_callback("/(\w+)$/", "word_to_upper", $str);
```

If you're using PHP 5.4 or greater, you can supply the callback as an anonymous function:

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/(\w+)$/", function ($match) {
  return strtoupper($match[1])
}, $str);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he means the last word "string" into "STRING", based on his title. However, your answer is perfect for his example. :)

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
$str = 'This is a very long string';

echo $str."<br/>";

function replaceMe($str = "")
{
    $words = explode(" ",$str);
    $totalwords = count($words)-1;
    $lastword = $words[$totalwords];
    $words[$totalwords] = strtoupper($lastword);
    $str = implode(" ",$words);
    return $str;
}

echo replaceMe($str);
?>
```

Output:

This is a very long string
This is a very long STRING

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = 'This is a very long string.';

function lastWordUpper($str){
$temp = strrev($str);
$last = explode(" ", $temp, 2);
return strrev(strtoupper($last[0]). ' ' .$last[1]) ;
}

echo lastWordUpper($str);
```